# Convert datetime without timezone

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, timezone

I have date in string: "2013-07-22T08:51:38.000-07:00"

When I [try parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) this string, I receive date with offset of timezone.

How can I make it without timezone offset?

---UPDATE---

it is that I receive: `DateTime.Parse("2013-07-22T08:51:38.000-07:00") = 7/22/2013 7:51:38 PM`
but I need to receive `7/22/2013 8:51:38 AM` - DateTime without offset.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "with offset time zone"? Please show your code, what you expected to receive, and what you actually received. And consider using `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: Please see my update in a question

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the DateTime property of DateTimeOffset.

Example:

```
string s = "2013-07-22T08:51:38.000-07:00";
var dateTimeOffset =DateTimeOffset.Parse(s, null);
Console.WriteLine(dateTimeOffset.DateTime);
```

Outputs:

```
22/07/2013 08:51:38
```

Comment: Plus one for this!  Helped me fix a big bug with our code today!

Comment: Is there a way to do this before an HTTP Handler is called?

Answer (score 6):

you can try this.

> DateTimeOffset.Parse("2013-07-22T08:51:38.000-07:00").DateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below one

```
        string s = "2013-07-22T08:51:38.000-07:00";

        DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(s);

        Console.WriteLine(d.Date.ToShortDateString());
```

Comment: if it been 2013-07-22T08:51:38.000 parse works fine.

Comment: but '2013-07-22T08:51:38.000-07:00' does offset time.

Comment: You can use DateTime object directly Console.WriteLine(d);

Answer (score -3):

If you have a `DateTime` object, you can use the `Date` property on it to receive just the date.

Comment: This is not a good answer since the date itself may be modified by the timezone.