# Datetime function converting one date older time

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
string date = "2017-01-05T00:00:00+00:00";
string time = Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

I am getting the above date from my client database, i am trying to convert that time to string but when i executed it was returning 01/04/2017 . why this is converting one day before ?

Comment: This could be time zone related. It looks like you have a +00:00 at the end.  This usually signifies time zone offsets.  So if your not in the same timezone the default Format provider may give you the time relative to where you are. look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402049/convert-datetime-without-timezone

Comment: It worked for me, Thank you @Hack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my bad. Here goes:

Yes I agree its a timezone offset issue, but this will work anyways:

```
string date = "2017-01-05T00:00:00+00:00";
string time = DateTimeOffset.Parse(date).DateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: This is also returning the same value.