# C# Converting string to DateTime without using DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

I'm trying to bring over facebook events to my website. They will be coming from different regions. For example, an event is in Eastern Time (-4 hours difference from UTC) and my local time is Central time (-5 hours difference from UTC). 
I am calling their graph API from a console app. I get the date of the events like this:

```
// get event items
me = fbClient.Get(url);
var startTime = me["start_time"];
var endTime = me["end_time"];
```

the start time shows: "2017-04-30T13:00:00-0400" object {string}

When I try to convert that string into a DateColumn type, it changes the output time to:
    var dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(startTime);
    {4/30/2017 12:00:00 PM}

It shifted the hour from 13 -> 12, how do I convert the string into date using DateTime and not using DateTimeoffset?

This examples shows how to do it using DateTimeOffset, but I need mine in DateTime type?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19403747/1019042

Comment: Maybe http://nodatime.org/ has some usefull methods for doing this. I would think that you need to tell the datetime object that the time your working with is in UTC -4

Comment: `DateTime` can only store local time and UTC, not other time zones, that's why it's converting. Why do you want to avoid `DateTimeOffset`? Isn't this what it's for?

Comment: `DateTimeOffset` has a `DateTime` property - use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DateTime` property of `DateTimeOffset` like the answer accepted in the link you've provided.

Or, if you *really* like to do it just with `DateTime` you can if you cut the timezone from the string:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(startTime.Substring(0,19), 
                              "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", 
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```